# What's the song playing in HxH: The Last Mission when Kurapika fights?

Tags: music, hunter-x-hunter

There's a song playing in *Hunter x Hunter: The Last Mission* at around 54:34 when Kurapika fights.

What is the title of the song?

Answer (score 2):

The name of the OST piece you are referring to is namer [Persuation](https://youtu.be/Y8yOlmi8pz4).